# Numeros pares, y numero de terminos a desplegar

Tags: java

Tengo una duda, realize el siguiente programa que me devuelven los numeros pares que estan dentro de un limite que el usuario otorga por teclado, ¿Es posible alguna manera para que me despligue, el numero de terminos pares en vez de los que se consideran dentro del limite?
ejemplo:
Ingrese limite:

5

Los numeros pares son:

2,4,6,8,10

En vez de:

2, 4

```
    Scanner  sc = new Scanner (System.in);
    int li=0;
    System.out.println("Ingrese la cantidad de numeros pares: ");
    li= sc.nextInt();
    for (int i =2; i<= li; i++)
    {
        if(i%2==0)
        {
            System.out.print(i+ ", ");
        }

    }
    System.out.println("");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  //Haz un bucle for que se repita tales veces dependiendo de cuántos números pares necesites

  Scanner  sc = new Scanner (System.in);
    int cant=0;
    System.out.println("Ingrese la cantidad de numeros pares: ");
        cant= sc.nextInt();
    for(int i=1;i<=cant;i++){
    System.out.println(2*i);// el valor de i va incrementando a medida que va pasando el bucle for (1, 2, 3...n)
}
/*    Por ejemplo, la salida para el valor 10 serían, 10 iteraciones en el bucle for:
    -1: 1*2=2
    -2: 2*2=4
    -3: 3*2=6
    -4: 4:2=8
    -5: 5*2=10
    -6: 6:2=12
    .
    .
    .
*/

//A petición también lo hago con números impares:
Scanner  sc = new Scanner (System.in);
        int cant=0;
        System.out.println("Ingrese la cantidad de numeros pares: ");
            cant= sc.nextInt();
        for(int i=0;i<cant;i++){ //comienzo el valor i desde cero
        System.out.println(2*i+1); //sumo un valor a la salida
```

Comment: Tambien pense lo mismo, pero lo que pasa es que tambien tebo hacerlo con numeros impares, y con los numeros impares no puedo multiplicar cada valor *3

Answer (score 1):

Aquí una solución para hacer lo que necesitas y poder elegir qué queremos obtener, par o impar. Espero que te sirva, lo he comentado para que entiendas lo que hago en cada línea.

**Código:**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Ingrese la cantidad de numeros: ");
        int cantidad = scanner.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Desea par o impar? (1 = par, 2 = impar): ");
        int tipo = scanner.nextInt();

        boolean isPar = tipo == 1 ? true : false;

        // Aquí guardaremos los números encontrados
        ArrayList<Integer> numeros = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 999; i++) {

            // Si ya tenemos x números, salir del for
            if (numeros.size() == cantidad)
                break;

            if (isPar) {
                // Par
                if (i % 2 == 0) {
                    numeros.add(i);
                }
            } else {
                // Impar
                if (i % 2 != 0) {
                    numeros.add(i);
                }
            }
        }

        // Imprimir
        for (Integer numero : numeros)
            System.out.println(Integer.toString(numero));
    }
}
```

**Resultado:**

> Ingrese la cantidad de numeros: 5
>
> Desea par o impar? (1 = par, 2 = impar): 1
>
> 0 2 4 6 8